# Database and Authentication Design Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, mongoid

I have a Rails 3.1 application. I'm planning to use Devise for auth and Mongoid for DB storage. So basically there will be two different types of users: Clients and Developers. Each of them has different abilities, Client can post a project, Developer can response to project's creator. So somehow we have to separate them. I think they both can use User model (probably embedded in Profile or Client or Developer model). Client won't have any profile, but Developer will.

So I came up with several ideas:

- Client and Developer models, each with different fields but each
  embeds User model. But then we have to provide one login form for
  both...
- Another ideas is there should be User model, and Client and Developer
  which inherit from User. Then we can just authorize User but also we
  will need to somehow access profile data.

Your ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

How about just adding a "type" field to the user model?

Comment: But there will be a big diff between Client and Developer. If we inherit them from User then (probably) Client and Developer are stored in User model w/ "type" field + different field sets. Then the question is how to make Client or Developer object from that User object

Answer (score 0):

> Client and Developer models, each with different fields but each embeds User model. But then we have to provide one login form for both...

I'm not sure why this is a problem, exactly? Why do you want two different login forms?

I would make two different classes, and have them *mix in* User, which would contain the common functionality.

Comment: Sorry for my a bit stupid English. I meant I want only 1 login form. :D